# How to cross-compile checksum algorithm of OpenSSL for Monetdb5?

Tags: openssl, cross-compiling, intel, monetdb, xeon-phi

I'm trying to cross-compile the Monetdb5 (11.21.19) using the intel icc compiler in order to port Monetdb to Xeon Phi.

My configure command is:

```
./configure CC=icc CFLAGS=-mmic --prefix=/home/xxx/monetdb/phiMonetdb --host=x86_64-intel-linux --with-perl-libdir=/usr/lib/perl/ --with-python2-libdir=/usr/lib/python2.7 --with-python3-libdir=/usr/lib/python3.4/  openssl_CFLAGS=-I/home/xxx/monetdb/build/include/openssl openssl_LIBS=-L/home/xxx/monetdb/build/lib zlib_LIBS=-L/home/xxx/monetdb/build/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/home/xxx/monetdb/build/include
```

I get this error:

```
checking for openssl... yes
checking for MD5... no
checking for RIPEMD160... no
checking for SHA1... no
checking for SHA224... no
checking for SHA256... no
checking for SHA384... no
checking for SHA512... no
configure: error: OpenSSL library found but checksum algorithm required for MonetDB5 not found
```

For your information, I've already cross-compiled OpenSSL 1.0.0 and put the header files and libs in:

```
openssl_CFLAGS=-I/home/xxx/monetdb/build/include/openssl openssl_LIBS=-L/home/xxx/monetdb/build/lib
```

How can I let it find the checksum algorithm?

Comment: dude you are on your own on this one. this is so esoteric i don't even know where to start helping you. sorry. I would say if you can't get it like OpenSSL you should probably not try to get it running on the Phi in the first place.